# Trigger compara múltiples resultados

Tags: mysql, trigger

Estoy empezando a trabajo con triggers en mysq y me he quedado atascado en los siguiente:

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER `prestamo_positivo` AFTER UPDATE ON `prestamo`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE AUX VARCHAR(10);
SET AUX=(SELECT A.id_cliente FROM PRESTATARIO A, PRESTAMO B WHERE A.numero_prestamo=OLD.numero);
IF(NEW.cantidad = 0) THEN
    DELETE FROM `prestamo` WHERE numero=OLD.numero;
    IF(AUX = (SELECT id_cliente FROM PRESTATARIO)) THEN
        INSERT INTO `mensaje`(mensaje, id_usuario) VALUES ("Renegociar prestamos del cliente",AUX);
    END IF;
END IF;
END; //
```

El problema es que el segundo "IF" está comparando un valor con una subconsulta que devuelve múltiples resultados. ¿Tendría que guardar los resultados en una tabla temporal e ir comparando el valor con cada tupla? Y si es así, ¿cómo se programaría esa lógica en triggers mysql?

Comment: Si pones AUX en el Where del select id_cliente .... te devolvera algo si existe no? asi no tienes que comparar. No se si la idea te ayuda. Es decir, insertas si existe ese id_cliente nada mas

Comment: El problema está en que la variable auxp puede seguir cogiendo múltiples resultados...